# PHP EMAIL Не отправляется картинка

Tags: php, изображения, email, отправка

Пытаюсь отправить по электронной почте письмо с HTML-разметкой и картинкой, которая генерируется PHP-скриптом. Но получателю приходит письмо без картинки (вместо картинки пустое место).
Мое письмо выглядит примерно так:

```
<p>Какой-нибудь текст...</p>
<p>Картинка:</p>
<p><img src="http://mysite.com/img.php"></p>
<p>Какой-нибудь текст...</p>
```

В img.php такой код:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 100);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, 0x555555);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Если открыть ссылку `mysite.com/img.php`, то картинка отображается корректно. В самом письме прописан `Content-Type: text/html`.
Получателю приходит письмо, даже не в спам, текст отображается правильно, но вместо картинки -- пустое место, а Firebug сообщает, что реальный размер картинки 1х1 px, хотя я задаю другой размер. При этом если я отправляю картинку не из php-скрипта, а просто с сервера `<img src="http://mysite.com/img1.png">`, то у получателя она отображается. Но мне нужно отправлять именно сгенерированную картинку. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо указать что первая часть ссылки это http-сервер. Соответственно нужно указать схему (http: или https:) например `http://mysite.com/img.php`

Воспроизвел ситуацию. Скрипт, который генерирует картинку взял ваш (один в один). Скриптом отправляю следующее письмо:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <img alt="" src="http://froloff.su/test1.php" width="23" height="23">
    <br>
    <img alt="" src="//froloff.su/test1.php" width="23" height="23">
    <br>
    <img alt="" src="froloff.su/test1.php" width="23" height="23">
    <br>
    Test images
  </body>
</html>
```

У третьей картинки Яндекс вообще убрал атрибут `src`. Остальные показываются нормально. Причем картинка генерируется с размерами 50×100, и проксируется Яндексом в оригинальном размере.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, не помогло.

Comment: Какой клиент почты?

Comment: Клиент от yandex.ru В полученном письме картинка выглядит так: `<img src="https://resize.yandex.net/mailservice?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fimg.php&amp;proxy=yes&amp;key=c8d2b76745cc544f6641f0c69b7f72b0">`

Comment: А если прописать размеры картинки у тега `img`?

Comment: Прописывал и размеры, и alt, и рамки, и стили, и оборачивал разными тегами (p, div, span), и в разные части письма вставлял (начало, середина, конец) - разницы никакой. Может быть, проблема в php-скрипте, который генерирует картинку?

Comment: Возможно проблема в сервере (например Яндекс не может достучаться до вашего сервера). Я повторил ваш php код и отправил письмо на ящик @yandex.ru. Картинка пришла в нормальном виде

Comment: Действительно, проблема в сервере. Попробовал отправить с другого и картинка пришла в лучшем виде. Спасибо вам за помощь! P.S. Знать бы еще, почему с того сервера не доходит?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Вычитал из статьи https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/206508/
следующее

> Если вы используете inline-картинки, то в img-src нужно разрешить протокол «data:».

Я использовал для этого http://b64.io/
Но закодированные картинки не отображались в gmail. Он просто удалял все из `src`. Поэтому я в `src` оставил прямую ссылку, и добавил `srcset` с закодированной картинкой.

```
<img src='https://host/img.png'  alt="img" srcset="data:image/png;base64,PD94.........jwvc3ZnPg==" style="display:block; height:38px; min-width:497.5px;">
```

Также этот способ позволяет добавить `svg` в `html` письмо с фолбеком для `png`. В `src` ставите `png` картинку, а в `srcset` - `svg`.